# Changing CSS background on <html> tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Using jQuery, how can I change this CSS?

```css
html {
    background: yellow;
}
```

This does not work:

```
$('html').css('background','red');
```

Comment: `$('body').css('background', 'red');`? I don't think you can style the `<html>` element.

Comment: try jQuery('html').css('background','red');

Comment: $('html').css('background-color','red'); works

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
$(document.body).css('background-color','red');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d5VjH/2/)

```
$('body').css('background-color','red');​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html').css('background-color','red');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9C5tC/

Comment: @Homer6 jQuery doesn't have any method named `style`

Comment: Are you on some other planet where you go to that link and it's not a red background?

Comment: @Homer6 You changed your code to use `.css()` instead of `.style()`. Before, you were using `$('html').style()` which doesn't exist and obviously was what we were referring to; but nice try.

Answer (score 0):

$('body').css({
            'background-color': 'red'
        });

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed as below.

```
$(document.body).css('background','red');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Your style is gonna apply to the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is this:

you can define a style class like this in your `<head>` element

and name it for example « redback » :

```
<style type="text/css">  
.redback 
{
background:red; 
}
</style>
```

and after that you can add this script in the `<body>` element like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html').addClass("redback");
      });

</script>
```